# changing my database to MySQL in WSO2-AM throws error upon starting the server

Tags: mysql, wso2-api-manager

/usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/bin/wso2server.sh: line 135: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/jdk/jdk-11.0.8+10
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
andes [org.wso2.andes.wso2.internal.QpidBundleActivator] INFO : Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
callhome [org.wso2.carbon.callhome.internal.CallHomeActivator] DEBUG : Activating CallHome agent
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,195]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 5.4.0-48-generic, amd64
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,219]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/jdk/jdk-11.0.8+10
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,220]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 11.0.8
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,220]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10,AdoptOpenJDK
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,221]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,221]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/tmp
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,221]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : wso2, en-US, Etc/UTC
[2020-09-25 07:51:08,643]  INFO - DefaultCryptoProviderComponent 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2020-09-25 07:51:09,445]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2020-09-25 07:51:09,840]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2020-09-25 07:51:15,939]  INFO - ConsentManagerComponent ConsentManagerComponent is activated.
[2020-09-25 07:51:16,366] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while starting Binary TCP Transport.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:257) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:149) ~[?:?]
at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:218) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryEventServer.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:182) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.26.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
[2020-09-25 07:51:16,361] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while starting Binary SSL Transport.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:257) ~[?:?]
at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:201) ~[?:?]
at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.(SSLServerSocket.java:136) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:70) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:73) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinarySecureEventServer.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:136) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.26.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
[2020-09-25 07:51:16,443]  INFO - DataBridgeDS Successfully deployed Agent Server
[2020-09-25 07:51:18,562] ERROR - AuthorizationUtils Could not set authorizations for the root.
Caused by: Error! DB error occurred while checking is existing system role for : admin & tenant id : -1234
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! DB error occurred while checking is existing system role for : admin & tenant id : -1234
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1491) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:560) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(RegistryAuthorizationManager.java:161) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.AuthorizationUtils.setRootAuthorizations(AuthorizationUtils.java:274) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.addRootCollection(UserRegistry.java:417) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.init(UserRegistry.java:340) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$100(UserRegistry.java:73) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$2.run(UserRegistry.java:261) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.(UserRegistry.java:258) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.(UserRegistry.java:237) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getUserRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:427) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:292) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:276) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:262) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:219) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:598) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]

Comment: maybe try and share with the community what you've done so far to try and fix the error, and how the error started to apear. Just Throwing the error in a question will not get far without context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another service or server is already using the configured ports. Check for port usage and try to change the port number to a different port

Answer (score 0):

As the error says "Address already in use", please check for the already running processes by executing the following command and start this server after stopping the other servers.

```
ps -aux | grep wso2
```

Or you can set a port offset to this server by changing the following configuration at <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml file. Make sure to uncomment the configuration too.

```
offset=5
```